# Jquery lightweight iso 8601 Datepicker for mobile phones

Tags: jquery, mobile, datetimepicker

Does anybody know i good Jquery (not jquery-mobile or jquery-ui) **lightweight** Datepicker which supports **iso 8601** and mobile phones?

I like this one
http://curioussolutions.github.io/DateTimePicker/

... but this dateTimePicker does not support iso 8601 :/

Comment: google provided this: http://stefangabos.ro/jquery/zebra-datepicker/

Comment: I would just use HTML5 date/time picker as XaxD pointed out, but implement moment.js for the date verification (to format and ensure it looks like ISO-8601).  Something to consider when most people implement ISO-8601 is that technically the week starts on Monday, so if you are developing for the US, you need to make sure the weeknum corresponds (i.e., 2014 has 53 weeks)

Answer (score 0):

HTML5 implements derivatives of iso 8601 in its date/datetime functionality. 
Have you considered skipping jquery and implementing `<input type='date' name='dateval' />` or `<input type='datetime-local' name='datetimeval' />`?

Answer (score 0):

Refer this link for datepicker which suports both iso and mobile devices
http://tjvantoll.com/2012/06/30/creating-a-native-html5-datepicker-with-a-fallback-to-jquery-ui/